# Clicking "code" and copy/pasting xml (schema) displays only first line

Tags: support, markdown, editor, code, xml

While writing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548811/xml-schema-key-in-sequence/1548859#1548859) I clicked "code" and cut and pasted XML schema into the question. For some reason, all this then displayed was the first line `"<?xml. . ."`. I fixed this by manually selecting and re "codifying" the text. But I shouldn't have to!

Thoughts? Observations? Is this true of all XML?

Answer (score 2):

What happened was that only ended up indenting the first line of code. For code to show up properly every line needs to be indented by four spaces.

What you can do instead is paste your code in, then go back and select it and press the code button (or Ctrl-K). That indents it after the fact so it shows up right. That's how I fixed your post, I highlighted the XML and hit the code button.

Comment: interestingly, I did this too, we must have edited it simultaneously. If you can, try to edit this post, and take a look at whats happening here (my post is being cut off).

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit here. :-(